# Music progress bar

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipod

I am currently writing a music app based on Apple's one, and I want to add a progress bar to it.

How can I make a progress bar to show the progress of a music that is playing in the default iOS's iPod app on my app?

Comment: What are you using to play the music?

Comment: My app shows the default iPod app's information, so iPod app is playing the music

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to take a look at the [MPMusicPlayerController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008221) class reference — specifically the `currentPlayBackTime` property. Never played with it, but looks like you want to take that and render it somehow in the interface.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I accomplised this
In the header file I declared these variables.

`NSTimer * currentTimeUpdateTimer;`

`'UISlider *timeSlider;`

`BOOL userIsScrubbing;`

`- (IBAction)handleScrubberTouchDown:(id)sender;`

`- (IBAction)handleScrubberTouchUp:(id)sender;`

`- (IBAction)handleScrub:(id)sender;`

In the main file now under the viewDidLoad method, I ran an NSTimer
`currentTimeUpdateTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(updateCurrentiPodItemTime) userInfo:NULL repeats:YES];`

`userIsScrubbing = NO;`

After that, it was a matter of updating everything.

```
- (void)updateCurrentiPodItemTime {
    MPMediaItem *nowPlayingItem = [self.musicPlayer nowPlayingItem];

if (nowPlayingItem == nil) {
    self.minLabel.text = @"00:00";

} else {
    NSNumber *duration = [nowPlayingItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration];
    double currentTime = self.musicPlayer.currentPlaybackTime;
    self.minLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%02d:%02d", (int) currentTime / 60, (int) currentTime % 60];     
    self.maxLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%02d:%02d", [duration intValue] / 60, [duration intValue] % 60];

    if (!userIsScrubbing)
        self.timeSlider.value = (float) currentTime;
    }
}

- (IBAction)handleScrubberTouchDown:(id)sender {
     userIsScrubbing = YES;
}

- (IBAction)handleScrubberTouchUp:(id)sender {
    userIsScrubbing = NO;
}

- (IBAction)handleScrub:(id)sender {
    self.musicPlayer.currentPlaybackTime = timeSlider.value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a timer to fire every second (1.0) and get it to call an method to update the progress bar like the one below:

```
- (void) updateProgressBar:(NSTimer *) timer {
    if (currentPlaybackTime != lengthOfSong) {
        [self.progressBar setValue:self.musicPlayer.currentTime];
    }
    else {
        [timer invalidate], timer = nil;
        [self.progressBar setValue:lengthOfSong];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a [UIProgressView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIProgressView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to your view and update it periodically.